# Why loss remains same for every epochs in my regression model?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, model, conv-neural-network

The below is the code for it.

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, validation_split=0.1)

train_generator = datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    df,
    directory=img_data_dir,
    x_col="image_name",
    y_col=["top_x", "top_y", "bottom_x", "bottom_y"],
    target_size=(WIDTH, HEIGHT),
    batch_size=32, 
    class_mode="other",
    subset="training")

validation_generator = datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    df,
    directory=img_data_dir,
    x_col="image_name",
    y_col=["top_x", "top_y", "bottom_x", "bottom_y"],
    target_size=(WIDTH, HEIGHT),
    batch_size=32, 
    class_mode="other",
    subset="validation")
```

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(VGG16(weights="imagenet", include_top=False, input_shape=(HEIGHT, WIDTH, CHANNEL)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(64, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(64, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(4, activation="sigmoid"))

model.layers[-6].trainable = False

model.summary()
```

```
STEP_SIZE_TRAIN = int(np.ceil(train_generator.n / train_generator.batch_size))
STEP_SIZE_VAL = int(np.ceil(validation_generator.n / validation_generator.batch_size))

print("Train step size:", STEP_SIZE_TRAIN)
print("Validation step size:", STEP_SIZE_VAL)

train_generator.reset()
validation_generator.reset()
```

```
adam = Adam(lr=1e-4)
model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss="mse")
```

```
history = model.fit(train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=STEP_SIZE_TRAIN,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=STEP_SIZE_VAL,
    epochs=10)
```

The below is the results of each epoch,

Epoch 1/10
20/20 [==============================] - 376s 18s/step - loss: 436570.7812 - val_loss: 524766.6875
Epoch 2/10
20/20 [==============================] - 14s 732ms/step - loss: 436464.6250 - val_loss: 524765.2500
Epoch 3/10
20/20 [==============================] - 14s 721ms/step - loss: 436464.2188 - val_loss: 524765.1250
Epoch 4/10
20/20 [==============================] - 14s 721ms/step - loss: 436464.1875 - val_loss: 524765.0625
Epoch 5/10
20/20 [==============================] - 14s 722ms/step - loss: 436464.1875 - val_loss: 524765.0625
Epoch 6/10
20/20 [==============================] - 14s 707ms/step - loss: 436464.1875 - val_loss: 524765.0625
Epoch 7/10
20/20 [==============================] - 14s 715ms/step - loss: 436464.1875 - val_loss: 524765.0000
Epoch 8/10
20/20 [==============================] - 14s 713ms/step - loss: 436464.1875 - val_loss: 524765.0000
Epoch 9/10
20/20 [==============================] - 15s 741ms/step - loss: 436464.1250 - val_loss: 524765.0000
Epoch 10/10
20/20 [==============================] - 17s 827ms/step - loss: 436464.0625 - val_loss: 524765.0000

Plot for it,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qOhz.png)

Comment: The loss value is very large. Have you checked whether the value range of the targets fit the output range of the network?

Answer (score 0):

With a short skim through your code, it seems that this line of code is hindering your model from training:

```
model.layers[-6].trainable = False
```

From the [Keras documentation:][1]

> Layers & models also feature a boolean attribute trainable. Its value can be changed. Setting layer.trainable to False moves all the layer's weights from trainable to non-trainable. This is called "freezing" the layer: the state of a frozen layer won't be updated during training (either when training with fit() or when training with any custom loop that relies on trainable_weights to apply gradient updates).

Training a model is about updating the weight matrices, so this might be hindering in optimising loss. Try setting this to True and see what happens. I have never worked with CNNs in Keras though. Maybe this line freezes a layer which you didn't intend to freeze?

[1]: [https://keras.io/guides/transfer_learning/#:~:text=trainable%20to%20False%20moves%20all,trainable_weights%20to%20apply%20gradient%20updates](https://keras.io/guides/transfer_learning/#:%7E:text=trainable%20to%20False%20moves%20all,trainable_weights%20to%20apply%20gradient%20updates)).